# Multiple UITableViews with a shared custom table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a story board with a tab view where each tab has a table view.

The tables show different items that look the same (feed, favorites, etc) - so each cell actually looks the same.

I know I can recreate the cells in each table but its a pain every time I want to adjust something. Currently the code (UITableViewCell) is shared but I was wondering if there is an easy way to extract the UI as well (the custom cell) so it will be shared as well between the tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by making the cell in a xib file. If your table view is made in a storyboard, delete the cell that you get with it, since you won't need that one. Create your cell in a xib, and then in the table view controllers, register the nib with whatever identifier you want,

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Your nib name here" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

That code can go in viewDidLoad. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, just dequeue a cell with that same identifier, and you will get a cell of that class and with the UI you made in the xib file.

Comment: The perfect explanation.  Note too that in some cases, it may be better to: make your own custom view (so, something like "all your buttons" or "the main layout of the cell" or whatever) and then just include that view, in the cells as needed.  Often that allows you to "customise each one a bit" or whatever your situation calls for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it worked, in a way. On my "storyboard cell" I had a segue leading to a view for each item, do I need to create it manually now? (same goes for other segues coming from buttons within the item)

Comment: @DoronGoldberg, yeah, that's the trade off of using a nib based cell. You won't be able to connect segues to it, so you'll need to make the segues from the controller instead, and call performSegueWithIdentifier in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (or in your button's action method).

Comment: Hi Again :) So making the segue which opened the cell item was easy - my problem is now with the internal buttons since the table cell doesn't have the performSegue.... How can I tell the parent the button was clicked so it will call the segue? any better solution except notifications? (somehow get the event?)

Comment: @DoronGoldberg, there would be several ways, but typically, you add the button's action in cellForRowAtIndexPath and make the controller the target. Give the button a tag equal to the indexPath.row so you can identify which row the button was in, and call performSegue from the action method.